# eb awscli cant deploy from git directory

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, gitlab, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm getting started with the ElasticBeanstalk AWS CLI and I've changed some of my workflow around. Previously I deployed from a directory above my git repository (which is a clone of a private GitLab directory), and shifted things around.

Before it was structured like this:

```
-- some_dir
 |-- .ebextensions
 | |- some_files 
 |
 |-- my_git_directory
   |- .git 
   |- some_files
```

And when I run `eb deploy`:

```
[some_dir] $ eb deploy
... Everything is awesome.
```

But now, I've moved to try and deploy from the git directory, but things aren't working:

```
-- some_dir
 |-- my_git_directory
   |-- .ebextensions
   | |- some_files 
   |- .git 
   |- some_files 

[some_dir/my_git_directory] $ eb deploy
... Everything sucks.
ERROR: An error occurred while handling git command.
Error code: 128 Error: fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

Now its all busted, and deploy no longer works. I've tried adding a [branch](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-reference-branch-environment.html) and [deploying a staged version](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-configuration.html):

```
$ eb branch
usage: eb (sub-commands ...) [options ...] {arguments ...}
eb: error: unrecognized arguments: branch

$ eb deploy
ERROR: This branch does not have a default environment. 
You must either specify an environment by typing "deploy my-env-name" or set a default environment by typing "eb use my-env-name".
$ eb use  django-env2

$ eb deploy --staged
... Nope, still busted
```

Answer (score 42):

So I got it solved and it is surprisingly basic, but it might help others.

If you move where you are deploying from you need to re-initialise *something* (not sure what), and it was fixed by running:

```
eb init
```

Then everything worked fine again.

Comment: Wow. Such a simple solution for such a mind-boggling problem. Thanks a million.

Comment: This is very helpful, thnaks.

Comment: This solved my 403 error on eb create! 
ERROR: CommandError - An error occurred while handling git command.
Error code: 128 Error: fatal: unable to access {my codecommit repo}  The requested URL returned error: 403